# What is the purpose of findAll() returning Iterable<T> in CrudRepository interface

Tags: spring-boot, iterable, crud-repository

Whenever you have a repository extending CrudRepository such as:

```java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
    //something 
}
```

and you want to use the method `findAll()`:

```java
Iterable<T> findAll();
```

You will get an iterable. Obviously, I could convert the Iterable into a list, like this:

```java
public List<Employee> findAll() {
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    employeeRepository.findAll().forEach(employees::add);
    return students;
}
```

Or I could Override the `findAll()` method on the repository or even I could simply go with `JpaRepository` instead, but my questions are:

1. What is the purpose of getting an Iterable in the first place? By converting it into a List am I going against the whole purpose of using CrudRepository?
2. If indeed is a fine approach to convert the Iterable into a List. What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Hope somebody can give me some insight on this.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the purpose of getting an Iterable in the first place?

Briefly speaking, returning `Iterable<T>` may be useful, as not only `List<T>`s are `Iterable<T>`s, and you might want to return something that is *not* a list;

> What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

I'm not sure what you consider as *most efficient*, but casting would work just fine:

```java
public List<Employee> findAll() {
    return new ArrayList<>((Collection<? extends Employee>) employeeRepository.findAll());
}
```